# awk output first two columns then the minimum value out of the third and fourth columns

Tags: awk

I have a tab delimited file like so:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
a 5 y:3.2 z:5.1
b 7 r:4.1 t:2.2
c 8 e:9.1 u:3.2
d 10 o:5.2 w:1.1
```

For each row, I want to output the values in the first and second columns, and the smallest number out of the two values in the third and fourth columns.

```
col1 col2 min
a 5 3.2
b 7 2.2
c 8 3.2
d 10 1.1
```

My poor attempt:

awk -F'\t' '{min = ($3 < $4) ? $3 : $4; print $1, $2, min}'

One reason it's incorrect is because the values in the third and fourth columns aren't numbers but strings.
I don't know how to extract the number out of the third and fourth columns, the number is always after the colon..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F'[ *:]' 'NR==1{print $1,$2,"min";next} {print $1,$2, $4<$6?$4:$6}' file

col1 col2 min
a 5 3.2
b 7 2.2
c 8 3.2
d 10 1.1
```

Comment: The original question indicated the input has tab-separated values, so to address that, one possibility would be to write: `awk -F'[\t:]' ...`.