# simpler way to extract and count data

Tags: shell, awk, count, cat

I need to extract specific information from my data and the summarize it.

I have 246 files that I need to do the same thing.

So I did

```
 for f in *.vcf; awk -F"\t" 'NR>1 {split($10,a,":");
              count10[a[7]]++}
        END  {for (i in count10)
                if (i>0.25)
                  sum += count10[i];
              print sum }' "$f" > ${f}.txt
```

I get new files for each old file which contain information I extracted from the old file ( some integers )

I then concatenate the new files by using cat function to produce one final big file

Is there a simpler way to concatenate  all files without producing single new files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [awk output first two columns then the minimum value out of the third and fourth columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34780828/awk-output-first-two-columns-then-the-minimum-value-out-of-the-third-and-fourth)

Comment: Sample input data and expected output would improve the quality of this question.

Comment: Without sample input and expected output we'd just be guessing at the best way to do whatever it is you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the last line in your code to look like below, it will then keep appending to your FINAL output file as shown below

```
for f in *.vcf; awk -F"\t" 'NR>1 {split($10,a,":");
          count10[a[7]]++}
    END  {for (i in count10)
            if (i>0.25)
              sum += count10[i];
          print sum }' "$f" >> FINAL.txt
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

quick and dirty

```
rm Summary.txt 2>/dev/null 
for f in *.vcf; awk -F"\t" 'NR>1 {split($10,a,":");
              count10[a[7]]++}
        END  {for (i in count10)
                if (i>0.25)
                  sum += count10[i];
              print sum >> Summary.txt }' "$f"
```

if you explain a bit more, the first for at shell level could be skipped using only a awk directly

Comment: You need to quote the file to which you're redirecting (`"Summary.txt"`).

Comment: and don't unnecessarily put output redirection inside an awk script, put it outside of it: `awk 'script' input >> output`?